# Python, PyQt5, botones, y pasaje de parámetros

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

```py
class Dialog_Alta_Profesores_Pnd(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,tipo):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        mod_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
        uic.loadUi(mod_path / "Ventanas/aaProfesores_PND.ui", self)

        self.line_email.setText(tipo)
        self.boton_aceptar.clicked.connect(self.ff_boton_aceptar_clicked)
        self.boton_cancelar.clicked.connect(self.ff_boton_cancelar_clicked)

    # Metodo que controla el boton "Aceptar"
    def ff_boton_aceptar_clicked(self):
        self.line_partido.setText(str(tipo))
```

Hola! Tengo un pequeño problema. Como se ve en el código, recibo un string que se llama "tipo" el cual uso para realizar un pequeño control. Yo hago la prueba en la linea que dice "self.line_email.setText(tipo)" y ahí funciona correctamente, ahora, cuando presiono el botón, la misma variable "tipo" se convierte, por alguna razón que desconozco en tipo bool, ya que al imprimirlo en el lineEdit "line_partido" solo imprime False, cuando, según dice el line_email la variable contiene, por ejemplo, la palabra "profesor".
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero que guardes la variable en la clase mediante el init.

```
class Dialog_Alta_Profesores_Pnd(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,tipo):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.tipo = tipo # Añade esto

     def ff_boton_aceptar_clicked(self):
        self.line_partido.setText(self.tipo) # Para poder hacer esto
```

Es posible que el argumento sea reemplazado por algun motivo, pero de esta manera tienes una versión guardada de ese parametro.

Comment: GRACIAS! Ésta fue la solución.